# NumPy function to find symmetric and asymmetric part of tensor / matrix / array

Tags: numpy

Is there a special function in NumPy that find the symmetric and asymmetric part of an array, matrix or tensor. I somehow seem to be lacking the correct Numpy term (really running out of English synonyms for "symmetric" at this point) to find the function.

The math isn't too complicated to code on its own, but I'm interested if Numpy has a faster algorithm:

```
A = A(s) + A(a)
A(s) = 0.5 * (A + A(^T))
A(a) = 0.5 * (A - A(^T))
```

Comment: This seems simple enough that there may not be a built-in implementation. I'd recommend you write a function that does your decomposition and move on.

Comment: Indeed, an often heard expression among Python developers is 'not every possible function that can be defined in one line has to be included in the standard library'. Moreover, you want a faster algorithm, but I see no obvious way to speed this up without implementing it in C, and even then the gain will be small (factor 2 or so?), since addition, multiplication and transposition should already be optimized enough. Did you profile your code and is this function a bottleneck? If not, it is premature optimization and you are wasting your time.

Comment: I haven't thought about it in that way. And no, the code is bottleneck-free. Being new to numpy just made me assume that there would be a function. But I am not thinking like a programmer enough to see that there is no need for a special function of the code is fast enough. Thanks to both of you! (And consider making the comments answers)